# Strange Move Assignment Operator Signature

Tags: c++, pytorch, rvalue-reference, rvalue, move-assignment-operator

I came across an unfamiliar move assignment operator signature in Pytorch' tensor backend (ATen, [source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/877c96cddfebee00385307f9e1b1f3b4ec72bfdc/aten/src/ATen/TensorOperators.h#L14)).
Just out of curiosity, what does the `&&` operator do at the end of

```
Tensor & Tensor::operator=(Tensor && rhs) &&
```

While I'm familiar with move semantics and the usual copy/move constructor and assignment operator signatures, I could not find any documentation online about the syntax above.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what this operator does, how it differs from the usual move assignment operation, and when it should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects of a class used as  expressions can be rvalues or lvalues. The move assignment operator is a member function of a class.

This declaration

```
Tensor & Tensor::operator=(Tensor && rhs) &&
```

means that this move assignment operator is called for rvalue object of the class.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A & operator =( A && ) &
    {
        std::cout << "Calling the move assignment operator for an lvalue object\n";
        return *this;
    }

    A & operator =( A && ) &&
    {
        std::cout << "Calling the move assignment operator for an rvalue object\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;

    a = A();

    A() = A();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Calling the move assignment operator for an lvalue object
Calling the move assignment operator for an rvalue object
```

That is in this statement

```
    a = A();
```

the left hand operand of the assignment is an lvalue.

In this statement

```
    A() = A();
```

the left hand operand of the assignment is rvalue (a temporary object).

Comment: lvalues and rvalues are expressions, not objects . Objects can be automatic, static, dynamic, temporary etc.   There is no such thing as "rvalue object". The ref-qualifiers relate to the value category of the expressions, not any property of the object that the expression designates.  I mention this as the topic is commonly misunderstood , which is in some part due to sloppy use of terminology .

Comment: @M.M I meant objects used in expressions.